# Are there more special numerals like 廿?

Tags: cantonese, number

In Hong Kong herbal tea shops, you will see a tea called "廿四味" (24 flavours)

(you will also hear "廿蚊" to mean "20 dollars" in small shops)

In this case 廿 ([niàn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ni%C3%A0n) or [pán](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A1n)) has the meaning "20".

Are there any other chinese numerals that represent unusual numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not only in Cantonese. People in several south provinces say these words. And most Chinese are familiar with `廿` ([niàn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ni%C3%A0n) or [pán](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A1n)) and `卅`, even though they don't usually say it.

1. `卅` (sà) means 30
2. `卌` (xì) means 40
3. `皕` (bì) means 200

Comment: cool. I like `皕`. `百＋百` joined into one character. Can you do the same with `萬＋萬`?

Comment: No, there is only `皕`, though I agree it's cool to combine two `萬`. And be careful to use `皕` and `卌`. I guess 99% native speakers have no idea about it.

Comment: 廿 is also commonly used in the Shanghai dialect. Just thought I'd put it out there, e.g., 廿四路 (Bus route 24).

Comment: How is 廿 pronounced in Shanghainese?

Comment: @jogloran `niàn`. Since my mother is from Shanghai, I know a little Shanghainese.

Answer (score 3):

halfelf's answer is correct, but I'll say a little more about how they're used in Cantonese, since the behaviour of these abbreviations is a little unusual there.

廿 *jaa6* indeed abbreviates 二十 *ji6 sap6*. Similarly, 卅 abbreviates 三十 *saam1 sap6*. But 卅 is pronounced *saa1aa6*, an unusual tone contour.

Abbreviations for numbers 40 and above are formed regularly: *sei3aa6*, *ng5aa6* and so on.